# achieving "ssh-copy-id" effect without knowing password?

Tags: ssh

I have full access to `server1`.

When I am on `server1`, I can `ssh` to `server2` without password:

```
local $ ssh myuser@server1
Welcome to Ubuntu ...
myuser@server1:~$ ssh user2@server2
Welcome to Ubuntu ...
user2@server2:~$
```

I would like to login to `server2` directly:

```
local $ ssh user2@server2
```

The problem is, I don't know the password for `server2`.

I went to `server1`, listed the contents of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Then I `ssh` to `server2` and copied those lines at the end of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` there.

But when I try to `ssh user2@server2`, it's still asking me for password. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need the password.

Comment: Add the `-v` option to your `ssh` commands. Add multiple `-v` to get much more data. Unnecessary for first level diagnosis. Compare results. Read `man ssh`.

Comment: "I don't know the password for server2" seems suspicious. Who manages server2?

Comment: I guess it's possible that server2's SSH server is configured with publickey as an authentication option when connecting from server1 but not from other clients... or even configured to allow [host-based authentication](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Host-based_Authentication) from server1

Comment: @waltinator I forgot the password, and I'd rather not jump through the hoops needed to get it reset.